# Compute $ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{3n^2+n-1}}{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}}$

Tags: calculus, limits

> Compute $$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{3n^2+n-1}}{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}}$$

I did the following:

$$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{\frac{3n^2}{n^2}+\frac{n}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}}}{\frac{n}{n^2}+\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}}} = \frac{\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{1}}=\sqrt3$$

However, the correct answer is different. Why am I wrong?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: $n+\sqrt{n^2-1}\simeq 2n$

Comment: You *are* wrong, but without seeing your work it's impossible to point out *where* you got wrong.

Comment: Divide everything by n

Comment: I divide everything by $n^2$

Comment: If you divide by $n^2$ then ${\sqrt{a}\over n^2} = \sqrt{a\over n^4}$

Comment: $n/n$, not $n/n^2$, then $1+\sqrt1$.

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand

Answer (score 6):

By dividing the numerator and the denominator by $n$, you should have
$$\frac{\sqrt{\frac{3n^2}{n^2}+\frac{n}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}}}{\frac{n}{n}+\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}}}=\frac{\sqrt{3+\frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{n^2}}}{1+\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{n^2}}}.$$
Instead at your denominator we have $\frac{n}{n^2}+\sqrt{\frac{n^2}{n^2}-\frac{1}{n^2}}$.

Then what is the final limit?

Answer (score 3):

Discarding the low order terms (which become negligible when $n$ grows), the expression has the same limit as

$$\frac{\sqrt3 n}{n+n}.$$

Answer (score 1):

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{3n^2 + n-1}}{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}}
$$

Factor out $n$, thus:
$$
\frac{\sqrt{3n^2 + n-1}}{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}} = \frac{n\sqrt{3 + {1\over n} - {1\over n^2}}}{n\left(1 + \sqrt{1- {1\over n^2}}\right)} = \frac{\sqrt{3 + {1\over n} - {1\over n^2}}}{1 + \sqrt{1- {1\over n^2}}}
$$

So your limit becomes:
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\sqrt{3 + {1\over n} - {1\over n^2}}}{1 + \sqrt{1- {1\over n^2}}}
$$

Now what happens to ${1\over n^k}$ when $n\to\infty, k\in\Bbb N$?

Comment: $0$. Thank you!

Comment: @J.Doe Note that even though $1\over n^k$ tends to $0$, the whole limit is not. It's just ${1\over n^k}$ "disappears".

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat heuristic and informal argument: *(note: a guide to formalize it follows)*

As $n \to \infty$, the term of greatest degree dominates the growth of a polynomial. In other words, in a cubic $f(x) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$, as $x$ grows larger and larger, $f(x) \approx ax^3$. This idea generalizes to all polynomials and like expressions (expressions of "rational" degree, like $x^{1/2}$ or $x^\pi$ or whatever, and sums thereof, for example).

With that idea in mind, we examine:

$$\sqrt{3n^2+n-1} \approx \sqrt{3n^2} = n \sqrt 3$$

Similarly,

$$\sqrt{n^2 - 1} \approx \sqrt{n^2} = n$$

Thus,

$$ \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{\sqrt{3n^2+n-1}}{n+\sqrt{n^2-1}} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty}\frac{n \sqrt 3}{n+n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \sqrt 3}{2n} = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt 3}{2}=\frac{\sqrt 3}{2}$$

---

A more formal, alternate argument can be obtained by dividing through the numerator and denominator by $n$, as touched on in other answers, but I feel my approach is more intuitive.

---

You can also make the original argument more rigorous by considering what it means to be "[asymptotically equivalent](https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Asymptotic_equivalence)," as noted in the comments by Bernard. Essentially, two functions $f,g$ are asymptotically equivalent if

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = 1$$

We also know, provided the limits exist, we can "distribute" the limit into the fraction as so:

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} = \frac{\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} f(x)}{\lim\limits_{x \to \infty} g(x)}$$

which means with the above that two functions are asymptotically equivalent if

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \lim_{x \to \infty} g(x)$$

In that light, this essentially gives us a means to make substitutions into the limit given. Since

$$\lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{3n^2+n-1} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \sqrt{3n^2}$$

we can make that replacement in our limit, for example. Of course, spelling out all the details is something I'll leave to you. ;)

Comment: (+1) If you replace $\approx$ with ‘asymptotically equivalent’, this becomes perfectly rigourous.

Comment: Huh, I never knew this would actually be the basis for a proper formal argument. Thanks, I'll have to look into it and edit it in. ^_^